# Measuring GPIO current with INA219

Tags: sensor, current

I'd like to build a simple circuit that does the following:

- controls a RGB LED (RPi 4 has 4 PWM outputs, so I could use 3 of them to control the LED)
- measures the current draw of each PWM output, with an ability to read these measurements using a program on RPi.

After some research, I stumbled upon INA219, which should allow me to measure the current. However, is it true that I'd need 3 of INA219 to be able to measure 3 PWM outputs?
Is there any better alternative for my use case?

// Adding circuit diagram (simplified)
[image]

Instead of measuring 3 PWM outputs, I'd just measure the current of the diode. Is it OK?

Comment: Please draw a circuit diagram. GPIO current will likely be insufficient to drive the LED strip directly, and INA219 measures DC current (which is either 0 or maximum), not PWM effective current (which depends on duty cycle). How precise you need the measurement to be?

Comment: Single led or LED strips? 3V or 12V? 1W or 3W, 5mA or 350mA? Any link for reference? Can these help? (1) https://components101.com/diodes/1-watt-led, (2) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563073/led-lighting-for-use-in-miniature-tanks.

Comment: Little if anything to do with the Pi.

Comment: It would be a single LED (something like https://www.amazon.com/Tricolor-Multicolor-Lighting-Electronics-Components/dp/B01C19ENDM).

Comment: The measurement does not need to be very precise, it could be even a resolution of 1mA. Hmm, if INA219 is not able to measure the effective current of PWM output, what should I use?

Comment: Anothe idea - it should be enough for me to measure just the combined diode current - then I'd connect the INA219 just behind the diode, after its common cathode (or anode, the variant doesn't matter for me). Would that be good?